# In iOS project with two targets one file has errors in one target while it compiles for the other

Tags: ios, swift

I have a project with two targets where one Swift file is a member of both targets.
One target compiles without errors, while the other target shows errors in the above mentioned file.

The file is quite simple. It's just the following struct:

```swift
struct Item : Codable
{
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String = ""
    var amount: Double?
    var unit: String?
    var onList: Bool = false
    var done: Bool = false
    var store: String?
}

extension Item: Equatable
{
    public static func ==(lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool
    {
        return
            lhs.id == rhs.id &&
                lhs.name == rhs.name &&
                lhs.amount == rhs.amount &&
                lhs.unit == rhs.unit &&
                lhs.onList == rhs.onList &&
                lhs.done == rhs.done &&
                lhs.store == rhs.store
    }
}
```

The error are:
[image: compiler errors]

I've no idea where to look for differences. I've checked the build settings, both targets are set to "Swift 5" at "Swift Language Version".

What else should I check?

Dirk

Comment: By the way, you do not need to write your `==` method for `Equatable`. If you check all your fields you can let the compiler synthesize it for you by only writing: `extension Item: Equatable { }` That's it.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you the `import Foundation` at the top of your file?

Comment: No problem... I run into it regularly, common mistake!